# Ocultar menú sticky en versión móvil

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Uso un menú sticky en mi web: `www.doblem.xyz`.

En la versión móvil, quiero que una vez que se haga click en el menú movil, y luego, en el menú, se pinche en una sección, el menú sticky se oculte.

```
<header class="row" id="myHeader">

        <div id="logo" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">

               <a href="../index.php"><img src="../img/logo_blanco.png" class="img-responsive"></a>

        </div>

        <!-- La caja "menuMovil" solo aparece en resoluciones de moviles
         (Collapsing The Navigation Bar BS-->
        <div id="menuMovil" class="navbar-header navbar-inverse">

                <!--pull-left: forzamos a colocarlo a la izquierda
                    data-toogle: collapse: Generar acción colapsable
                    data-target: clase a la que afecta el "data-toggle"
                -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" >

                        <!-- Las tres lineas del botón-->
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Debemos indicar que esta caja es colapsable y de que se trata de una barra de navegación colapsable
        -->
        <nav id="menu" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">

                      <li class="active"><a href="../index.php">Volver</a></li>                              
                </ul>

        </nav>

</header>
```

El código del sticky js:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction()
};
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");


    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Menu_movil();

function Menu_movil(){
$("#boton_movil").click(function()
    {   $('#menu').show();
        $("#menu").click(function()
        {
            $('#menu').hide();
            Menu_movil();

        })
    });
}
```

Cuando se hace click en el div #boton_movil (que oculta el menú en resoluciones moviles) se muestra el menú original (#menu)
Cuando se clickea #menu, este debe ocultarse de nuevo, lo cual se consigue con $('#menu').hide();
Pero debemos dejar listo de nuevo la funcion MenuMovil() por si se clickea de nuevo en #boton_movil, mediante recursividad.
Pero en la segunda interacción, debemos mostrar de nuevo #menu ya que lo habiamos ocultado previamente.

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad, ya que las que son solo codigo se las trata asi. podrias explicar que hace este codigo y porque soluciona el problema? mira por favor [answer]

Comment: @gbianchi lo acabo de editar.

Comment: Genial! gracias por ocuparte :)

Comment: No es del todo correcta, pero al menos me "ha funcionado" algo de lo que buscaba.

Comment: Recuerda aceptarla una vez que pase el periodo de tiempo necesario!